# Gradient of vector valued function of two variables

Tags: real-analysis

I have to determine the directional derivative of a vector valued function of two variables say $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$. I am stuck because I don't really know what the gradient of such a function looks like. I want to use the gradient to determine the directional derivative since we used it for real valued functions or is my approach wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of the directional derivative of a function $f$ at a point $\alpha$ in the direction of $v$ is $$D_v f(\alpha) = Df(\alpha) \cdot v.$$ Therefore, as an example, consider $f(x,y) = (x^2+y^2, \cos (y))$ with $\alpha = (1,2)$ and $v = (1,1)$. We find that $$Df(\alpha) = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 \\ 0 & - \sin(2) \end{bmatrix}$$ and the directional derivative is $$Df(\alpha) \cdot v = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 \\ 0 & - \sin(2) \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 6 \\ - \sin(2) \end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: And the second equation ($Df(\alpha)=...$) is actually $[f'(x)]$ which is also called the functional matrix or simply $f'$ right?

Comment: it is dubbed the Jacobian Matrix

Comment: and the determinant of it is called the Jacobian right?

Comment: @Vinyl_coat_jawa Yes, that's correct. :)